# How to get list of Hangout calls from any Google API in Java?

Tags: java, google-plus, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

I tried to find in [Google+ Hangouts API](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/) some function for listing of Hangout calls, like in this screenshot from the right side of my Google+ screen:

[image: screenshot from Google+]

I think, I can achieve that with [gapi.hangout.telephone.getCalls](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/api/gapi.hangout.telephone.html#gapi.hangout.telephone.getCalls). Is there any way how to do it in Java? Or in another server side language, just for illustration? Or should I use a different API or a function?

Thx.